# Authenticate Subversion users with svnserve AND SSH

Tags: ssh, svn, svnserve

When deploying my Subversion server, I don't like creating a system account for each user so I was thinking of another authentication method.

I would like to use only one system account with SSH and then authenticate users using `svnserve`.

I tried to configure SSH so that each user has a different key and a specific `svnserve` command with a specific `--tunnel-user`. I also added these users into my `passwd` file in my repository.

My problem is that `svnserve` does not use the `passwd` file to authenticate `--tunnel-user` names but allows to read and write as long as the SSH authentication has been done.

Is there a way to force `svnserve` to prevent a user not in passwd from reading or commiting in a repository?

**Edited:**

If there is no way to achieve this with my setup, is there another way to serve Subversion on SSH without creating a system account for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. While svnserve cannot do the authentication again with an SSH-authenticated user, it still can authorize it using the authz file.

So here is my setup:

- user `svn` is the main account and its home is `/var/svn`
- all users use `svn` account to SSH on the SVN server
- `svn` account has every public keys of every users in its `.ssh/authorized_keys`
- each public key is prefixed with `command="svnserve -r /var/svn -t --tunnel-user=<user1>"` (it is actually longer because I also disable tunnelling and co.)
- each repository in `/var/svn` has `authz-db = authz` in `conf/svnserve.conf`
- each repository has its own `conf/authz` file to list authorized users:

```
[groups]
developers = <user1>,<user2>

[/]
@developers = rw
* =
```

Now I can add a user by simply adding a new public key in `/var/svn/.ssh/authorized_keys` with a new `--tunnel-user` name and add this user name to all authorized repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Tunnel mode skips svnserve authentication in favor of SSH authentication by design.

> "... the connection is considered to be pre-authenticated ..."

You're trying to bend this approach into doing what it's not meant to do.  How about using a WebDAV setup over SSL (with users defined in the web server's authentication) instead?

Comment: Thanks for the info about SSH authentication skipping svnserve authentication, I now understand why my setup does not work. About your suggestion of using HTTPS, I considered it but I would rather use a key-based authentication that I consider more secure and easier to maintain. Any other idea how I could serve Subversion on SSH without creating a system account for each user?

Comment: You could use key based authentication with WebDAV.  You will still need some kind of authentication server, and configure your web server to use certificate based authentication.